# Where can I find external.php file in vBulletin?

Tags: php, vbulletin, forums

I want to know where is external.php can found in VBulletin. I want to see the code and create a similar file. Actually I want to get list of all the Forums and sub forums from vBulletin and make an xml. Then I would like to call it on an external PHP page.

Would like to get something like this on an external page

Forum Name | Views:10 | Last post by
Forum Name | Views:10 | Last post by
Forum Name | Views:10 | Last post by
Forum Name | Views:10 | Last post by
Forum Name | Views:10 | Last post by

Thanks.

Comment: More likey, you can do that from database info rather than vbulletin PHP code. The code for each page is abstract and involves many includes, so you're not likely to find everything you need on external.php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find external.php in the root of the forum folder. For example:

- If your forums are at example.com/forums/ or forums.example.com, then you can find external.php at `/public_html/forums/external.php`.
- Or if your forums are on the root of the domain then you'll find external.php at `/public_html/external.php`.

As others have said, I don't really imagine it to be of much use for what you want to achieve though.

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting to locate the file itself, you can do so on a unix system using the `find` command line function, by executing `find -name external.php`. However, like JAL pointed out, this information is going to come from the database, and external.php is liable just to show you how to access it or what you need to do to interpret the data. Explicit calls to the database would be more useful for the purpose you're describing.

Comment: Thank you, That means I will have to create another file which will just get the data using normal query. And then call it in another website.